# Branch.io parameters missing when appended to an existing link

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I am trying to make it so a user clicks a Branch.io link in the form 
`https://a.test-app.link/identifier?foo=bar`
and then be redirected to the AppStore to download the app. The app should then be able to grab the `foo` parameter during launch.

To debug this I have followed this procedure:

1. Create the link under the test environment.
2. Tap the link on the device.
3. Install app with Xcode.
4. Launch the app and read the parameters during launch with

   ```
   let branch = Branch.getTestInstance()
   branch.setDebug()
   branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
       if error == nil {
           // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
           // params will be empty if no data found
           print(params)
       }
   })
   ```

I have also set the correct API tokens in the info.plist file.

From what I understand, I should be getting by now my `foo` parameter within the `params` dictionary, but this is not happening. The only way to get parameters to work is by adding static ones using the dashboard. Furthermore, I'm even getting old parameters in the `params` dictionary that I have already removed from the dashboard, but no sign of the URL query parameters.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have an update and a probable cause, and this ended up being much more interesting than expected!

**TL;DR:** passing link data as a query string parameters works for both `app.link` *and* `test-app.link`. The real cause behind these symptoms is something else, but would never be encountered by a normal user.

#### Symptoms

Link parameters appended *to an existing Branch link* (for example: https://bnpo.app.link/identifier?foo=bar) do not reliably show up inside the app.

#### Cause

It turns out that at some point, Apple changed the behavior of mobile Safari so that when you enter a URL *that is also in your history*, Safari actually preloads the page as you type. To the Branch servers, this looks exactly the same a regular visit, so we create device fingerprints for each one of these 'visits'. You can actually see this in action by going to the [Link Clicks](https://dashboard.branch.io/#/liveview/link_clicks/view) page on your Branch dashboard, entering the URL for a Branch *that you have visited before* into the Safari address bar, and then watching all the link 'clicks' roll in.

The problem is the Branch SDK consumes device fingerprints sequentially from oldest to newest. If you have previously visited `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier` while testing, and then re-enter that URL with an appended query parameter (`https://bnpo.app.link/identifier?foo=bar`), Safari has already loaded `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier` before you even have a chance to type in `?foo=bar`.

This means your device now has two different fingerprints outstanding:

1. One for `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier`
2. Another for `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier?foo=bar`

Even though you press **Go** to trigger the launch of the app with the URL `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier?foo=bar`, the fingerprint for `https://bnpo.app.link/identifier` already exists, and is consumed first within the app because it is a older (by a second or two, depending on how fast you type).

If you then exit the app and launch it again immediately, you'll get the next fingerprint with the extra parameter.

#### Solution

This is a situation that would come up fairly easily during testing, but that real-life users are almost never going to encounter. It only occurs when manually typing in a URL that has already been visited, and then appending additional query parameters to it.

For testing purposes, simply relaunch your app repeatedly until you get no data (`+clicked_branch_link: 0`) from the Branch `init()` call during launch (to use up any outstanding fingerprints), and then either...

1. Type out your URL in full using Notes and paste it into Safari
2. Just open the URL from inside Notes

We'll add a cautionary note summarizing the above in our documentation. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: This occurs for any of our existing users who try to install via a branch link so I do not think it limited only to edge testing.

Comment: @MarkEssel unfortunately there are a ton of things that can cause these symptoms. This one was pretty specific to _extra_ appended query parameters. Are your existing users getting some params back, or none at all?

Comment: Sorry, a little bit late from my part, but thank you very much @AlexBauer for this complete explanation!

Comment: It took half day of efforts to reach to this.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** this answer is out of date. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358674/5394680) for what was determined to be the actual cause of the issue.

---

Alex from Branch.io here:

What you described is NOT the expected functionality, and I can verify on my end that this is not working correctly in the Test App configuration. I will pass this bug along to our engineers!

In the meantime, it appears that appending query params to *live* key links still works as expected. So if you do https://bnpo.app.link/identifier?foo=bar, `foo:bar` will come through.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Hi Alex, If I call http://domain?param=value for iOS 8 and app is installed then it uses url schema to open an app. URL schema only contains branch link so I need internet connection at that moment to know the query params.  Is it possible to read the param without internet?

Comment: @user3096733 you're very welcome. We're investigating this today!

Comment: @MrVaghasiya unfortunately you do need an internet connection to retrieve the params. It is conceivable that you could write a custom function to parse out the appended query param and route on it, but that would only work on iOS 8. You would also need an internet connection _anyway_ to have successfully opened the Branch link that triggered the redirect in the first place! Feel free to post a new question and tag it Branch.io if you want more info — I'll jump right in :)

Comment: @MrVaghasiya you should look into $deeplink_path -- that will be available synchronously if the browser opens the app directly. This works with URIs, but not Universal Links. (for Universal Links, you can simply append params and they will be available synchronously)

Comment: Thanks @st.derrick deeplink_path really helps in iOS 8!!